# Motion layout not animating views that are not its direct children

Tags: android, animation, android-motionlayout, android-motionscene

I have recently tried the `MotionLayout`, I works fine on a button when it is a direct child of the `MotionLayout` but the same motion scene does not work,  when I enclose the button in another layout, bu the parent layout is still `MotionLayout`.

First layout where the  button is direct child :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout

  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  app:layoutDescription="@xml/demo"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".Demo" >

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/yellow_button"
     />


  </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Second layout where button is indirect child :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/demo"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Demo"
>
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:id="@+id/l1"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/yellow_button"/>
 </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

The motion scene layout is below:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    <Constraint android:id="@+id/yellow_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <CustomAttribute app:attributeName="alpha"
            app:customFloatValue="0.0"/>

    </Constraint>
</ConstraintSet>

<ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    <Constraint android:id="@id/yellow_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        >

        <CustomAttribute app:attributeName="alpha"
            app:customFloatValue="1.0"/>

    </Constraint>

</ConstraintSet>

<Transition
    app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"

    app:autoTransition="animateToEnd"
    app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
    app:duration="2000"/>
```

**Is there any guideline that needs to be followed in these cases??**

OR

**Does this mean that only direct children of the `MotionLayout` can be animated with it?**

Answer (score 2):

This medium article (https://medium.com/google-developers/introduction-to-motionlayout-part-i-29208674b10d) by Google Developers says under the 'Limitations' section:
"MotionLayout will only provide its capabilities for its direct children — contrary to TransitionManager, which can work with nested layout hierarchies as well as Activity transitions."

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way to make it works, it involves a few lines of code and I have not tried it with so complex MotionLayouts but at least for a typically beautiful nested XML it works like a charm.

Check out this [animation example](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/NestedMotionLayout/blob/master/docs/images/NestedMotionLayout.gif):

### This is how XML hierarchy looks like

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/header_container_scene"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/header_background"
        android:foreground="@drawable/white_gradient"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/tonitan_unsplash"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_header_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        app:layoutDescription="@xml/child_header_container_scene"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/logo">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text_1"
            style="@style/Title.White"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/my_header"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/header_text_2"
            style="@style/Title.White"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/header_value"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/header_text_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/another_text_1"
            style="@style/Title.White"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/my_subtitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_text_1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/another_text_2"
            style="@style/Title.White"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:text="@string/subtitle_value"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/another_text_1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_text_1" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_app_title"
    style="@style/Title.Black.25"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:text="@string/my_title"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header_container" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/my_app_title"
    tools:listitem="@layout/rv_item" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

### The magic

As you can see in above XML, there are three scenes: activity_main_scene, header_container_scene, child_header_container_scene. Each one will take care about its direct children and the only missing thing is synch them up:

1. Implement MotionLayout.TransitionListener in your Activity, Fragment or independent class.
2. Create the scenes you need (in the example I have 3)
3. set up the transaction listener for each one (call this fun in onCreate, onViewCreated or something like that):

```
private fun setUpMotionLayoutListener() = with(binding) {
        rootContainer.setTransitionListener(this@MainActivity)
        headerContainer.setTransitionListener(this@MainActivity)
        childHeaderContainer.setTransitionListener(this@MainActivity)
    }
```

4. synchronise them using following code:

```
private fun updateNestedMotionLayout(motionLayout: MotionLayout?) = motionLayout?.let {
        with(binding) {
            if (it.id == rootContainer.id) {
                headerContainer.progress = it.progress
                childHeaderContainer.progress = it.progress
            }
        }
    }
```

And that's all!

[The complete example can be found here](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/NestedMotionLayout)